# How to parse the correct key and value for given string using Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing

I have a list:

```
key1:this is an{example{of an example}I like} key2:this is another example key3: this is secondary{example{of an example}}
```

I need to separate the key and compare the values of the keys by difference so the result I would like to obtain is:

```
{
  :key1 => 'this is an [example[of an example]I like]',
  :key2 => 'this is another example',
  :key3 => 'this is secondary[example[of an example]]'
}
```

Is something like this or something similar possible with Ruby or a Regex?

Comment: What do you want to return? A hash? A string?

Comment: I would like it to be hash. I currently tried to use split and regex to divide by ":" and "{}" thats as far as I got

Comment: I edited your question so that the desired return value looks like a hash. It's still not clear what your intention is with all those square brackets. Feel free to edit again to make that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:

```
def parse_into_hash(s)
  keys = s.scan(/\w+:/.map{|k| k.chomp(":")}
  values = s.split(/\w+:/).select(&:present?)
  Hash[keys.zip values]
end
```

This is not bullet-proof. It may fail if you have colons in the values or if any of the values are empty strings, but it will work for your example, and should get you started. You can make it more robust if you need to.

Comment: Thank you! I will build up from your example